# Unity Isometric Tilemaps Appear Jagged

Tags: unity, tilemap, isometric

[image]

I had issues using the isometric tilemaps feature in Unity. Whenever I try to place tiles, they don't seem to line up and create this jagged effect. I've tried messing with the anchor points and am a complete beginner at this.

Edit: My grid component looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of your grid component? It looks like your horizontal spacing may be slightly too large, or your vertical spacing too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your sceenshot, it looks like the top diamond of your sprite is about 104 pixels tall by 181 pixels wide - though the scene view might be resampling it at a different resolution than your source asset, so be sure to measure in your original texture to get the exact measurements.

That's about 57.5% as tall as it is wide. So in the Cell Size field of your Grid component, you'll want the height to be about 0.575 to a width of 1.0, instead of the 0.5 you have currently.

Again, this is a bit of a crude calculation based on the screenshot, so massage the numbers until you find a fit that looks right.